# Sql accounting Algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I'm needing help to build an algorithm for calculating AgingIncome (at least that's what they're calling it).

We sell two different services, X and Y, for location A - Z. All of those sales come in and at the end of a month, I sum up by the type of service sold by location.

Example: Location A sold $100 worth of service X. I want to account a part of that over the period of 8 years.

- First year, I want to account for 36% of that $100
- second year, 24%
- 3rd year 12%
- 4th year 8%
- 5th year 7%
- 6th year 6%
- 7th year 5%
- 8th year 2%

Since it's reported monthly, first year, first month would be 36/12=3% each month. Similarly, second year would be 24/12=2% per month and so on till the 8th year.

Also, if on the second month, I sell another $100 worth of service A at the same location, my calculation changes and that new amount is added to the remainder. i.e. month 2 would be 6%.

Do I have the right idea? At the end of each month, calculate for each location and type of service combination and build a table that spreads over the 8 year period, then going forward, just update that for each location?

Comment: As posted currently this question is lacking most of the details required for anybody to really be able to help.

Comment: You are likely to get an answer much faster if you provide table definition, example data and expected results instead of lengthy descriptions.

Comment: In terms of data, all I have are my transaction tables where sales are recorded. This is a brand new idea and I'm just looking for a logical approach to this computation. I have a table built with the % breakdown by year. There are two types of breakdown and that table should be used by the type of service sold.